# Remove specific java.net.CookieManager Cookie getting UnmodifiableCollection exception

Tags: java, cookies, httpcookie

I am using java.net.CookieManager & java.net.CookieHandler to track cookies. I need to remove one but keep all others. The problem is that the List return from the using cookieManger.getCookieStore().getCookies() is unmodifiable and therefore throws an exception when I attempt to remove the cookie. 
Here is the code regarding cookies:

```
public HttpProxy(String host, String port) {
    cookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    //other irrelevant code
}

private CookieManager cookieManager;

public void deleteGameCookie() {
    CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();
    List<HttpCookie> cookieList = cookieStore.getCookies();

    HttpCookie temp = null;
    // iterate HttpCookie object
    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieList) {
        try {
            String name = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getName().replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8").replace("%2B", "+");
            if(name.equals("catan.game")) {
                System.out.println("catan.game cookie found");
                temp = cookie;
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //System.out.println("Error decoding cookie... bummer...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    cookieList.remove(temp);
}
```

Is there a way around this or a better way to do this? 
I found a similar question about unmodifiable collections [here](http://www.cybertechquestions.com/how-to-resolve-javalangunsupportedoperationexception-in-java_37171.html) but it hasn't been answered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Erm ... did you read the javadoc for `CookieStore`?  Did you read where it *specifies* that the collection returned by `getCookies` is unmodifiable? Did you get to the methods whose names start with the letter "r"?

Comment: *"I found a similar question about unmodifiable collections here but it hasn't been answered."* - Frankly, I'm not surprised.  The answer would be "don't do that!".

Comment: I read that a little while after asking the question, maybe I should have removed it but I figured someone else might have missed that at first as well and benefited from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to use one of the remove methods on cookie store not try and work with the list directly.  see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that should do the trick:

```
public void deleteGameCookie() {
  CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();

  List<HttpCookie> cookiesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

  for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
    try {
      String name = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getName().replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8").replace("%2B", "+");
      if (name.equals("catan.game")) {
        cookiesToRemove.add(cookie);
      }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  for (HttpCookie cookie : cookiesToRemove) {
    cookieStore.remove(null, cookie);
  }
}
```

The code should also handle situation where no cookie was found and when there is more than one cookie matching your criteria.